# Numbers not formatting correctly in canvas text field

Tags: canvas, tkinter

[image]
[image]

Code snippet from picture:

```
        t1 = "År {}: {:25d}".format(2015, 41231226098)
        t2 = "År {}: {:25d}".format(2016, 3093)

        print(t1, '\n' + t2)  
        # Output:              # It formats nicely here as you can see:
        # År 2015:                      3093                       
        # År 2016:               41231226098

        # Now I update the two text fields... # Something goes wrong now
        self.DPcanvas.itemconfig(self.DP_helpBox_lab, text=label)
        self.DPcanvas.itemconfig(self.DP_helpBox_årxLab, text=t1)
        self.DPcanvas.itemconfig(self.DP_helpBox_åryLab, text=t2)
```

All the items that are drawn on the canvas have I chosen to call "self.
The two text fields you see on the gui program: "År 2016:               41231226098" and "År 2015:                      3093" are two different labels.

Code showing the creation of the two labels:

```
    self.DP_helpBox_årxLab = self.DPcanvas.create_text((width + 155), 45, anchor='w', font=f2, text='')
    self.DP_helpBox_åryLab = self.DPcanvas.create_text((width + 155), 67, anchor='w', font=f2, text='')
```

**Problem:**
Numbers are not formatted as intended when written in a canvas text field.

Comment: We can't tell what you intend. Whad do you expect to see? Please create a [mcve] that illustrates the problem. For instance, we need to see how you created the canvas items.

Comment: it looks like it uses font in which chars have different width and space is smaller - so it looks different than in console which use monospaced  font. Wikipedia: [Monospaced font](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font)

Comment: @furas Thanks a monospaced font like consolas helped. Should I delete this question?

Comment: Don't delete it. I add my comment as answer and it can be useful for other users.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it uses font which chars have different widths and `space` is smaller than other chars - so text looks different than in console which uses monospaced font.

Wikipedia: [Monospaced font](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font)